# Read all lines from text file to listbox C#

Tags: c#

It says I need an `String` after `ReadAllLines(...)` Can someone help me setup that.

I don't understand how I'm going to get the text file to `ListBox`.

```
private void futureButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ofd.Filter = "TXT|* .txt";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(DialogResult);
        listbox.Items.Add(lines);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know C#, but I think you have to use something like `ofd.Path` instead of `DialogResult` - you need a file name, not an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a collection of strings in one pass, use `AddRange()` instead of `Add()`. Also, you'll need to reference the [`FileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get the full path of the selected file.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

listbox.Items.AddRange(lines);
```

The call to `Add()` just ends up calling `ToString()` on the collection, so all you'll see is the class type, in this case `String[] Array`.

When you use `AddRange()`, it calls `ToString()` on each item in the collection. In the case of a collection of strings, you just see each string. If you were using a custom class you created, you'd have to either override `ToString()` so something sensible were displayed, or you could use a bit of LINQ in the call to `AddRange()`, to select the property you wanted displayed.